# Google Cloud Loadbalancer not working with App Engine Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, blobstore

We've just created a new Loadbalancer which works perfectly well with all our services. The only issue we have is with the Blobstore.

The initial blobservice request works - returning a URL for the upload. But executing that request (*/_ah/upload/*) fails with a 404. My understanding is that it should be redirected to the blobstore service which will then send a response with the upload id. This works fine without the load balancer.

I can't see a way to add the blobstore as a service, so I don't know what to do to make sure the request is routed to the correct place.

Any help is gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a known limitation with Blobstore when used in an HTTPS load balancer in App Engine.

With the App Engine to Blobstore service, the generated URL for upload is shared to [Google Front End](https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/design#google_front_end_service). When the Load Balancer is introduced, the App Engine URL is returned, and causes a 302 redirect. The returned URL is used as a relative path to connect via the load balancer, and as it is not aligned to the one expected by the GFE, a 404 response is thrown.

Blobstore is a legacy API and has been deprecated, and with the limitations it has, it is ideal to look for alternatives.

You can consider using [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage), as mentioned in this [overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore). It is possible to achieve the upload behavior through [Cloud Storage signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable) which bypasses the App Engine Upload component. It would be necessary to implement a further component to notify on completion, such as a Pub/Sub for new object creation, if that information is needed.

Besides Cloud Storage, you can check other replacement options for Blobstore in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/blobstore-ui#replacement_options).

Comment: Thanks Mabel! It sounds like we'll need to bite the bullet - I was hoping for a work around but that feels like an impossibility now. Thanks for confirming. All the very best, Guy